# SSD page reprogramming

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Is it possible to reprogram a page in a SSD (without erasing it) if the new data contains a subset of the previous data's one-bits?

I know that erasing to all-ones can only be done on the block level (and causes wear). My question is if SSDs can make use of the situation when the only modification needed is turning some ones to zeros, which I think might be possible without an erase.

I guess this is more than just a yes-or-no question. It might be physically impossible, unsupported by current circuitry/firmware or already being done. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to reprogram a page in a SSD (without erasing it) if the new data contains a subset of the previous data's one-bits?

In theory, yes.
A NAND flash page can be written more than once without an erase operation.
You can experiment with this on a SBC that has a (raw) NAND flash chip and U-Boot commands.

> It might be physically impossible, unsupported by current circuitry/firmware or already being done. Which is it?

The idea is not implemented in SSD firmware because it's impractical.

First, the time to read the original erase block and perform the comparison would be additional overhead for every write operation, and typically be wasted time because the expectation of a positive result is probably low.
The trade-off in reduced write speeds is probably not worth the minuscule increase in device life.

Second and more importantly, you are overlooking the need to update the ECC (error correction code) of the sector (which is typically stored in the OOB (out of band) area of the page).
If only the sector data area of the page is "written" without updating the ECC, then any subsequent read of that page would fail the ECC verification test.
The likelihood that the new ECC value is also like the page data (which only requires writing one-to-zero bits and no zero-to-one bits) is too low to consider.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I actually have a use-case where the probability would be rather high, but I was completely unaware of the use of ECC in SSD. Having looked into it, I must concede that my idea shall not be practical for NAND flash. However, it seems to me that the (much less commonly used) NOR flash might have the parameters I need - pages can be written to more than once, erasure is "expensive", and no ECC is used. Am I right?

Comment: NOR flash typically does not require ECC, but is more expensive and less dense than NAND. Here's a datasheet link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwi4ntDosLLgAhUJD3wKHX4YD3EQFjABegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.micron.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2Fdocuments%2Fproducts%2Fdata-sheet%2Fnor-flash%2Fparallel%2Fm29w%2Fm29w128g.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0rS-d3pzQkhRlYcWYERj3W